# Get Random Image with Button Click with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, random

I know this has been answered before, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this wouldn't work. I've checked, and re-checked, and everything looks like it should work outright, but I'm not sure what I would be missing with this. Here's what I have:

**JS:**

```
const images = [

      "https://assets.codepen.io/8689/lake-thumb.jpg",
      "https://assets.codepen.io/8689/photo-thumb.jpg",
      "https://assets.codepen.io/8689/gopro-thumb.jpg"
    ];
    
    function getRandomImage() {
      const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
      return images[rnd];
    }
    
    function changeImage() {
      const img = document.querySelector("#images");
      img.src = getRandomImage();
    }
    
    function init() {
      const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-image");
      btn.onclick = changeImage;
    }
    
    window.onload = init;
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="images"></div>

<a href="#" class="btn-img">Get Image</a>
```

**Codepen link:** https://codepen.io/ultraloveninja/pen/ZEOLKeV

It *should* work and show a random image on load and then when you click the link/button load up a new on. So, not sure why they wouldn't be showing overall and I'm not getting any errors in the console.

Comment: `<div id="images"></div>` that should be `<img id="images">` to work

Comment: btw from a UX point of view, it would be better to shuffle the array on load, then cycle through them with a modulo, else some clicks won't produce a new random and it will look like the click is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to investigate the issue step by step:

1. Make sure that `init` is actually running (add a console.log in the beginning of it - see/run the code below)
   OK, `init` works as you can see...
2. Make sure that you capture the button correctly (add a console.log with it)
   Oh, it's actually `null` and then there is an error of adding an event listener to a null value

Why is that? Oh, you have `btn-img` on the button, but `btn-image` in your code. Making both class names the same solves the problem.

The second problem you have is that the image should be `<img id="images">` and not a `div`

```js
const images = [

  "https://assets.codepen.io/8689/lake-thumb.jpg",
  "https://assets.codepen.io/8689/photo-thumb.jpg",
  "https://assets.codepen.io/8689/gopro-thumb.jpg"
];

function getRandomImage() {
  const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  return images[rnd];
}

function changeImage() {
  const img = document.querySelector("#images");
  img.src = getRandomImage();
}

function init() {
  console.log("Init works!") // NEW!
  const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-image");
  console.log("Button:", btn) // NEW!
  btn.onclick = changeImage;
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div id="images"></div>

<a href="#" class="btn-img">Get Image</a>
```

Comment: Whoops! Looks like it expanded my `img` to `images`. Anyways, that makes sense regarding the `img` to `div`, didn't see that originally. The only thing that is strange is the onload, which should populate a random image when the window loads, correct? Or am I reading that wrong as well. I did test it with a `console.log` output and that seems to work.

Comment: NM - I think I got it by adding the `changeImage()` in the `function init()`.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need an `<img>` instead of a `<div>` element and the class name is wrong for the `<a>` element here is a correction of your code

```js
const images = [

      "https://assets.codepen.io/8689/lake-thumb.jpg",
      "https://assets.codepen.io/8689/photo-thumb.jpg",
      "https://assets.codepen.io/8689/gopro-thumb.jpg"
    ];
    
    function getRandomImage() {
      const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
      return images[rnd];
    }
    
    function changeImage() {
      const img = document.querySelector("#images");
      img.src = getRandomImage();
    }
    
    function init() {
      const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-img");
      btn.onclick = changeImage;
    }
    
    window.onload = init;
```

```html
    <img id="images">

<a href="#" class="btn-img">Get Image</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<div id="images"></div>` tries to change its `src` here:

```
  const img = document.querySelector("#images");
  img.src = getRandomImage();
```

however it does not have an image source, since it's a div.

it should be: `<img id="images">` instead of the div.